# Register Postback of imagebutton inside gridview

Tags: gridview, rowdatabound

I have GridView control, in that one column is for linkbutton and one column is for imagebutton. On GridView RowDataBound event i have write code for changing backcolor of the row which is clicked. code is :

```
public void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ChangeRowColor(this)");
    }
}
```

where changeRowColor is javascript function. Now When i click on any row or linkbutton of the gridview it change the backcolor of that row. And Linkbutton has only clientclick type of event. so even after clicking on that the backcolor of row is still remains but on Image Button i have Serverside Function called onClick event so when i click on imagebutton it completes its task specified in Onclick event but then after the backcolor is not remaining as it is. The backcolor of row is also changed to its default colors.Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: `Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.` no one can tell you because you have not posted the code but only posted some code that adds an attribute.

Comment: Ok But i think i have mentioned flow of code

Comment: But it's not clear as to what the issue is. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: The background color of row retains when clientclick event called but it is not retaining when serverside event called.

Comment: Once you do a postback, the grid is recreated from scratch. You need to figure out if it is a postback and set the background color before returning the HTML to the client (browser).

Comment: yes i am also feeling same. now i am trying to call gridviewrowDataBound event on button click but i am not getting how to send arguments

Comment: What do you mean feeling the same-it's not a feeling but that's just how the web works.

Comment: ok my mistakes.